# MySQL - Why in this case a secondary index doesn't reduce the time of this query?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, query-optimization

As part of an experiment I'm trying to optimise this query, and for this example I am using [The Employee database][1] provided by MySql. The strategy I'm using is creating a secondary index on the birth_date attribute since theory texts recommend doing this on columns that are used in the WHERE clause.

By creating such index I was expecting a reduction in time of at least 40%
but that is not the case with this query. There doesn't seem to be an improvement in time, in fact it takes a bit longer on average. Could anyone tell me why this is happening?

```
SELECT employees.emp_no,
        employees.departments.dept_name,
        employees.first_name,
        employees.last_name,
        employees.birth_date,
        year(curdate()) - year(birth_date) AS yearsOld
FROM employees.employees
INNER JOIN employees.dept_emp ON employees.dept_emp.emp_no = employees.emp_no
INNER JOIN employees.departments ON employees.departments.dept_no = employees.dept_emp.dept_no
WHERE year (birth_date) < 1953
ORDER BY emp_no ASC;
```

Results:

Without secondary index:

Time taken on average:  0.728  sec

After creating secondary index:

```
CREATE INDEX myIndex2 ON employees(birth_date);
```

Time taken on average:  0.731  sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are **not** using the raw column value of `birth_date`. Only then an index can be used. When using a function like `year()` indexes are useless.

To make use of the index you can do this instead:

```
where birth_date >= '1953-01-01'
  and birth_date <  '1954-01-01'
```